# Equivalent of $_ENV['APACHE_RUN_USER'] in PHP-CLI

Tags: php

I'm running a PHP script from CLI interface.

How can I get the running user name like when I'm in Apache ( `$_ENV['APACHE_RUN_USER']` )?
At now I'm using `exec('whoami')`, but is not platform-indipendent.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to login to a system (windows, linux) to execute the php script in CLI, so who is the user that doing the execution? The current login user

Comment: This isn't true, I'm running she same script daemon from multiple crontabs and different users.

Comment: Regardless how many crontabs you have, there will be the only one user who actually executing script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `$_ENV['USERNAME']` and it may be portable at least between Win and Linux

Answer (score 4):

I had success with `$_SERVER['LOGNAME']`

Answer (score 1):

It seem to be system-dependent. On Ubuntu 10.04, I had to use

```
$_SERVER['USER']
```

In any case, to find out what to use on your system, you can use the following command to display all the global vars and find out where the current username is stored:

```
print_r($GLOBALS);
```